# Equation for the expected value of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I'm reading the book [Introduction to Stochastic Processes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486497976), p.24. In proving the expected value for 'any non-negative random variable $X$', the author provides the following equation for the expected value of a discrete random variable $X$ with values in $E$:

$$ 
\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{a \in E}aP\{X=a\} \\
&= \sum_{a \in E} \int_0^a dt  P\{X=a\} \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} dt \sum_{a>t} P\{X=a\} \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} P\{X > t\} dt \\
\end{align}
$$

The part I'm stuck on is the equivalency of the second and third expressions, and in particular the notation for the third:

$$ 
\sum_{a \in E} \int_0^a dt  P\{X=a\} 
= \int_0^{\infty} dt \sum_{a>t} P\{X=a\} 
$$

I'm reading the third expression as the product of a definite integral with value $= \infty$ and a sum over some subset of $E$ that is unknown since the value of $t$ is not specified. But that makes no sense. Can someone explain how this equation works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is skipping some intermediate steps:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{a \in E} \int_{t=0}^{t=a} dt  P\{X=a\}
&\stackrel{(1)}=\sum_{a\in E}\int_0^\infty I(t<a)P\{X=a\}dt\\
&\stackrel{(2)}=\int_0^\infty\sum_{a\in E} I(t<a)P\{X=a\}dt\\
&\stackrel{(3)}= \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{a>t} P\{X=a\}dt\\
\end{align}
$$
In step (1) we convert the integral from $0$ to $a$ into an integral from $0$ to $\infty$ by introducing the indicator function $I(t<a)$. In step (2) we interchange the integration and summation (which is legal because everything is non-negative). In step (3) we absorb the indicator function into the summation.

Note on the RHS of (3) the entity $\sum_{a>t} P\{X=a\}$ is the integrand, i.e., it's the function of $t$ that we are integrating from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$.  Your confusion is due to the text's unfortunate habit of placing the $dt$ to the left of the summation.

Comment: Thank you grand_chat. I couldn't have worked that out from my prior knowledge. Each of your steps involves something that is new to me, but it all makes sense. Do you know if there's some place in particular that I would look to learn about integrals of sums and sums of integrals? I don't recall this stuff from basic Calculus.

Comment: @MattMunson You may have covered Fubini's theorem in calculus -- this is the theorem that allows you to interchange the order of integration in a double integral. There is a generalization that handles interchanging the order of a double sum, or a combination of integral and sum, but this is normally not covered until you take a course in "real analysis". For more help you can look up "fubini" or "tonelli" on this stackexchange site (or elsewhere), for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1975047/215011